# Como usar o objects.filter em django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Boa tarde, eu tenho um model aqui no meu django Assunto, e quero fazer a listagem dela no html, porém todo assunto tem como chave estrangeira o id do model categoria, como eu faço uma variável pra receber o objects.filter só dos assunto que tenha como chave estrangeira o valor 1 por exemplo?

minha view

```
def index(request):
    assunto_jogo = Assunto.objects.filter()
    return render(request, “index.html”)
```

model assunto

```
class Assunto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', unique=True, max_length=150)
    descricao = models.TextField('Descrição')
    id_categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.nome
```

e categoria

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', unique=True, max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Comment: Será somente por essa id ou será por exemplo um componente html como por exemplo: select , raiobutton que vai ser escolhido e dizer a qual categoria desejaria ver os assuntos ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É bem simples, pegue a categoria e depois liste os assuntos relacionados a ela:

**Exemplo 1:**

```
categoria = Categoria.objects.get(id=1)
assuntos_da_categoria = categoria.assunto_set.all()
```

Ou filtre diretamente:

**Exemplo 2:**

```
assuntos_da_categoria = Assunto.objects.filter(categoria__id=1)
```